# Unused Arguments

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function Mark_FareTypeExcl , which I want to use to define Faretype of each row of my table.
I am using dplyr mutate to use this function to populate a derived column on my table

```
df= df%>%
        rowwise()  %>%
        mutate(D_FareType = Mark_FareTypeExcl(SRegion,TKT_DESIGNATOR, TOUR_CD) )
```

However, it gives an error -
Error in ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/IN", TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)),  :
unused argument (alist())

Can anyone help and let me know the issue.

---code---

```
Mark_FareTypeExcl = function(Region, TKT_DESIGNATOR, TOUR_CD){
  
  if(Region == "EMEAI"){
    
      FType = ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/CH",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Child Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/IN",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Infant Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("TO",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Tour Operator",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/OG",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares", 
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/CE",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares", 
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/CK",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares", 
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/CM",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares", 
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/CV",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares", 
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/CY",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares", 
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/C0",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares", 
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/C0",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Corporate Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("CA",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Government Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("DG",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Government Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("MZ",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Government Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("MIL",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Government Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("GR",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Group Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("401GBT",TOUR_CD, ignore.case = T)), "IT/Net Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("401GBB",TOUR_CD, ignore.case = T)), "IT/Net Fares",
              ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("834GH",TOUR_CD, ignore.case = T)), "IT/Net Fares", "")
              ))))))))))))))))))
  }
  
  if(Region == "APAC"){
    
    FType = ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/CH",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Child Fares",
            ifelse(isTRUE(grepl("/IN",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T)), "Infant Fares","",
            ))
  }

  
  return(FType)
}
```

Comment: Instead of nested `ifelse`s, use `case_when`

Comment: `ifelse()` is for vector operations; `isTRUE` is not.  You should drop all the `isTRUE` calls.  In addition, it's slightly risky to use `T` instead of `TRUE` in the `ignore.case = T` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr::case_when` that is very similar to your approach:

```
library(dplyr)
Mark_FareTypeExcl = function(Region, TKT_DESIGNATOR, TOUR_CD){
case_when(Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/CH",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Child Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/IN",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Infant Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("TO",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Tour Operator",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/OG",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares", 
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/CE",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares", 
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/CK",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares", 
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/CM",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares", 
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/CV",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares", 
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/CY",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares", 
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/C0",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares", 
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("/C0",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Corporate Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("CA",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Government Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("DG",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Government Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("MZ",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Government Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("MIL",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Government Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("GR",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Group Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("401GBT",TOUR_CD, ignore.case = T) ~ "IT/Net Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("401GBB",TOUR_CD, ignore.case = T) ~ "IT/Net Fares",
         Region == "EMEAI" & grepl("834GH",TOUR_CD, ignore.case = T) ~ "IT/Net Fares",
         Region == "APAC" & grepl("/CH",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Child Fares",
         Region == "APAC" & grepl("/IN",TKT_DESIGNATOR, ignore.case = T) ~ "Infant Fares",
         TRUE ~ "")
}
```

```
Mark_FareTypeExcl(Region = c("EMEAI","APAC"), TKT_DESIGNATOR = c("CA","/IN"), TOUR_CD = c("384GH","401GBT"))
[1] "Government Fares" "Infant Fares"
```

Comment: It may be better with a key/val data and fuzzyjoin

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to help you with your error, because your question is lacking a reproducible example (eg. the output of `dput(df)` so we can run your code). However we can do some general things to improve your chances to find the error.

First of all `ifelse` is useful, but it's very inefficient. And it does not generate very readable code. As in your case whenever we nest multiple `ifelse` statements it becomes almost impossible to read and find errors within. `dplyr` has an alternative that is much more efficient and readable called `case_when` which works by specifying a logical statement (`grepl` returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` which is logical), and then specifying the return value.

In addition to this you can remove many of your `ifelse` statements by changing your regex expressions to include "or" which is indicated with vertical bars `|`. This makes your code much more readable. Last but not least we can create a wrapper function around `grepl` so we dont have to specify the parameters every time we execute the function, or alternatively call `tolower` or `toupper` on our inputs prior to calling `grepl`, to improve performance slightly. All of this combined can be seen below:

```
Mark_FareTypeExcl = function(Region, TKT_DESIGNATOR, TOUR_CD){
  # ensure all is in upper caps for comparisons.
  TKT_DESIGNATOR <- toupper(TKT_DESIGNATOR)
  TOUR_CD <- toupper(TOUR_CD)
  Region <- toupper(Region)
  # Helper function so we dont have to specify all arguments to grepl every time.
  greplc <- function(x, which = TKT_DESIGNATOR)
    grepl(x, which)
  # Find the reagion and compare fare.
  if(Region == "EMEAI"){
    case_when(greplc('/CH') ~ 'Child Fares',
              greplc('/IN') ~ 'Infant Fares',
              greplc('TO') ~ 'Tour Operator',
              greplc('/OG|/CE|/CK|/CM|/CV|/CY|/C0') ~ 'Corporate Fares',
              greplc('CA|DG|MZ|MIL|GR') ~ 'Government Fares',
              greplc('GR') ~ 'Group Fares',
              greplc('401GBT|401BB|834GH', TOUR_CD) ~ 'IT/Net Fares',
              TRUE ~ '')
  } else if(Region == "APAC"){
    case_when(greplc('/CH') ~ 'Child Fares',
              greplc('/IN') ~ 'Infant Fares',
              TRUE ~ '')
  }else
    # If we are in an unknown region, throw an error
    stop("unknown region")
}
```

Note I have not "solved" your problem. One last thing we could do, is to try and remove the need for a call to `rowwise` by vectorizing the function. Currently your reason to call `rowwise` is your outer most `if` statements. But if we were to test our region first, we could include this in the helper function. I've taken the liberty to implement this in the function below.

```
Mark_FareTypeExcl = function(Region, TKT_DESIGNATOR, TOUR_CD){
  # ensure all is in upper caps for comparisons.
  TKT_DESIGNATOR <- toupper(TKT_DESIGNATOR)
  TOUR_CD <- toupper(TOUR_CD)
  Region <- toupper(Region) 
  # Pre-calculate region vector
  EMEAI <- Region == 'EMEAI'
  APAC <- Region == 'APAC'
  # Test whether we have an unknown region
  if(any(!EMEAI & !APAC))
    # Generate error string of the unknown regions.
    stop(sprintf('Unknown region(s): [%s]',
                 paste0(Region[!EMEAI & !APAC], collapse = ', ')))
  # Helper function
  greplc <- function(x, which = TKT_DESIGNATOR, region = EMEAI)
    grepl(x, which) & region
  # Find the reagion and compare fare.
  case_when(greplc('/CH') ~ 'Child Fares',
            greplc('/IN') ~ 'Infant Fares',
            greplc('TO') ~ 'Tour Operator',
            greplc('/OG|/CE|/CK|/CM|/CV|/CY|/C0') ~ 'Corporate Fares',
            greplc('CA|DG|MZ|MIL|GR') ~ 'Government Fares',
            greplc('GR') ~ 'Group Fares',
            # Tour CD
            greplc('401GBT|401BB|834GH', TOUR_CD) ~ 'IT/Net Fares',
            # APAC region
            greplc('/CH', APAC) ~ 'Child Fares',
            greplc('/IN', APAC) ~ 'Infant Fares',
            TRUE ~ ''
}

# Used as:
df %>% 
  mutate(D_FareType = Mark_FareTypeExcl(SRegion, TKT_DESIGNATOR, TOUR_CD))
```

Once again, both of these are untested as there is no reproducible example in the question